# What order does Gradle build modules in with parallel build enabled?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Want to know if a project would compile faster if like the one really big `common` module could be split into submodule so the dependency graph is less like a pyramid

```
  *    
 / \
*   *
```

and more like a square

```
*  *  <-- build top level dependencies faster because can build concurrently on multi core CPU 
|/ |
*  *
```

or does Gradle not build in the in order of the dependencies?

Was curios if project could build faster if higher level modules can be built in parallel.

**edit**

My understanding is that there is a task tree, and `Gradle` builds in order of the task tree, so that might be the direction I should look in.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle will not execute two tasks in the same project in parallel, it will only execute tasks from different projects in parallel. Once the task graph ordering is taken into account, Gradle will execute projects in alphabetical order.

If you want to understand the task tree, add the [task tree plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) to your build.

You can then do something like

```
gradle build taskTree
```

Which will ioutput something like

```
:build
+--- :assemble
|    \--- :jar
|         \--- :classes
|              +--- :compileJava
|              \--- :processResources
\--- :check
     \--- :test
          +--- :classes
          |    +--- :compileJava
          |    \--- :processResources
          \--- :testClasses
               +--- :compileTestJava
               |    \--- :classes
               |         +--- :compileJava
               |         \--- :processResources
               \--- :processTestResources
```

Comment: That seems correct in terms of the default behavior, but doesn't Gradle allow a parallel build Boolean? I forgot to mention that. Like wouldn't a `common` or `core` type Gradle module have to build first before like an `app` module?

Comment: Now say I split the `common` module into multiple modules, now will they build in parallel on a multi core CPU with the boolean enabled? And *then* the app module builds.

Comment: If that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, assuming no dependencies between the modules, they can build in parallel and app module will need to wait for them to complete